# Error Using MWPHotoBrownser

Tags: objective-c, xcode, syntax-error, sdwebimage, mwphotobrowser

I got this error when I'm using the MWPhotoBrownser and I have no idea how to fix it.

Semantic Issue "Cannot find protocol declaration for SDWebImageDecoderDelegate"

in the file MWPhoto.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MWPhotoProtocol.h"
#import "SDWebImageDecoder.h"
#import "SDWebImageManager.h"

// This class models a photo/image and it's caption
// If you want to handle photos, caching, decompression
// yourself then you can simply ensure your custom data model
// conforms to MWPhotoProtocol
@interface MWPhoto : NSObject <MWPhoto, SDWebImageManagerDelegate, SDWebImageDecoderDelegate>

// Properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *caption;

// Class
+ (MWPhoto *)photoWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
+ (MWPhoto *)photoWithFilePath:(NSString *)path;
+ (MWPhoto *)photoWithURL:(NSURL *)url;

// Init
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image;
- (id)initWithFilePath:(NSString *)path;
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

[image: this the error]

[image: this the app test that I made to test the MWPhotoBrownser]

I hope you guys could help me out. I'll be really glad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not imported the SDWebImage files into your project. They are mentioned in the MWPhoto.h file:

```
#import "SDWebImageDecoder.h"
#import "SDWebImageManager.h"
```

Copy all the files under MWPhotoBrowser/Libraries/SDWebImage folder from where you clone the git repositories of MWPhotoBrowser.

Comment: I didn't cloned it, I just download it and copied to my project folder. I did what the README file was saying.